Find the value of '?' in 4x4 table of numbers
Solve for ?











50
15
10
60


45
31
5
87


40
22
42
?


9
4
3
14




Hi William welcome to PSE could you please give us the source of this puzzle?

The entry is, or rather may be $85$, with the following way to guess it.
Take the first and the third columns. Add them.
To the result add four times the second column. We obtain:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
50 + 4\cdot 15+10\\
45 + 4\cdot 31+5 \\
40 + 4\cdot 22+42\\
 9 + 4\cdot 4+3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
120\\
174 \\
170\\
 28
\end{bmatrix}
=
2\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
60\\
87 \\
\bbox[yellow]{\ 85\ }\\
 14
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
There is a match with the last column at three places...

Note: This is the value that makes the given $4\times 4$ matrix have linearly dependent rows and columns. Well, the combination of columns is still "nice", so this is a puzzle plus for the value. (But one should never mention, here or elsewhere, the combination of the rows, it needs the weights / coefficients $1609$, $805$, $655$, $-15875$, or common multiples, except for the case when still not afraid to endure the consequences.)
